# Anaconda Navigator specifically does not display "base" on macOS BigSur (Version 11.7.9)

Tags: python-3.x, bash, macos, anaconda, computer-science

So after downloading the Anaconda Navigator - "Graphical macOS Installer" from their offcial website, when I input the command in the terminal "conda activate", "base" does not appear/show on my terminal.

Is there a reason for this, and how can I resolve this issue. In some other forums, they discuss about using zshell instead, but I will prefer not to go down that path.

I re-installed the Anaconda Navigator - "Graphical macOS Installer", again, due to complications that I had with it before. And when I activate conda, it dislayed "base" on the terminal, but now it doesn't.

I think I might have tweaked something on my bash_profile, but I am no longer sure what it may have been.

I will appreciate any suggestions, and welcome your feedbacks.

[Bash Version (at this current time)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LfS1.png)...